# GAE GO - html templates and data safety

Tags: html, google-app-engine, templates, go

When displaying a webpage through the use of [html templates](http://golang.org/pkg/html/template/) in Google App Engine Go application, does the passed data and/or raw template ever leave the App Engine, or just the final html output? For example, if I have a class

```
type Foo struct{
    Public string
    Secret string
}
```

and a template that only uses `{{.Public}}` argument, does the `{{.Secret}}` argument ever leave the App? Similarly, if there is a template that displays some special data if the `{{.Secret}}` argument is present through the use of `{{if .Secret}}...{{end}}`, is there any way to access that part of the html in any way when the `{{.Secret}}` argument is not present?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's your Go program that parses the template. This can take place on several GAE server instances. Assuming that *leaving* GAE means being sent over an HTTP/S connection over the public internet, then no - the output you send is the parsed HTML template.

It's not possible to access the part after `{{if .Secret}}` if it's not included in the final HTML that the client receives.

What you could do, however, would be to send the template and it's associated dataset encoded as `gob` or `JSON` over to your client, and let your client parse the template.